# How can I run a multiple-MATCH search without returning null?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have a sample query if you'd like to see an idea of the graph I'm going to be referring to:

`CREATE (u:User {name: "Tim Cook"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(t:Thing {name: "Italy"}), (t)<-[:TAGGED]-(p:Post {name: "Post 1"})<-[:WROTE]-(u1:User {name: "Elon Musk"}), (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u2:User {name: "Oprah"})-[:WROTE]->(p1:Post {name: "Post 2"}), (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u3:User {name: "Joe Biden"})-[:WROTE]->(p2:Post {name: "Post 3"})`

Also here: [image]

I am trying to get all posts where the user either follows the author directly (someone who "WROTE" a post) OR where the person follows a Thing that was "TAGGED" in a post.

So in the example query, if you are Tim Cook, you should receive Posts 2 and 3 because you follow the authors directly, and Post 1 because you follow Italy that was TAGGED in that post.

I've been searching everywhere, it's a hard thing to search for. Landed here. I'm using "OPTIONAL" so that if the user isn't following any people the first one doesn't crash the whole query, or if they aren't following any things, the second one doesn't crash. However, with how I did it below, it returns Null for either of the queries that are empty.

So if there are no matches for the first part and 6 for the second, I end up with an array of length 7. [null, post1, post2, ...post6].

How should I be doing this instead, please? Thank you in advance!

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (this)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u1)-[:WROTE]->(post:Post)
RETURN post
ORDER BY post.id
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (this)-[:FOLLOWS]->(t:Thing)<-[:TAGGED]-(post:Post)
RETURN post
ORDER BY post.id
```

`this` refers to the Tim Cook user node in the above example.

I also would like to return if the user follows the author (the User who "WROTE"). So I think I can add an "EXISTS" or is there a way to specify which query returned a post? E.g. if the post was returned by the first MATCH above, then they clearly follow the author. If returned by the 2nd, and not the first, then they don't. What's the best way to tackle this query/how should I be doing this instead, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the node in the middle of the path (user or tag) as a generic object, and thus from there use a multi-relationship type pattern matching :

````
MATCH (u:User {name: "Tim Cook"})
MATCH (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(thing)-[:WROTE|TAGGED]-(p:Post)
RETURN p.name

╒════════╕
│"p.name"│
╞════════╡
│"Post 3"│
├────────┤
│"Post 2"│
├────────┤
│"Post 1"│
└────────┘
```

From there, if you want to know if the user is following the author, it's just plain logic, you return if the node in the middle is of type 'User' (which would validate the assumption since the first relationship is FOLLOWS thing)

```
MATCH (u:User {name: "Tim Cook"})
MATCH (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(thing)-[:WROTE|TAGGED]-(p:Post)
RETURN p.name, ('User' IN labels(thing)) AS followingAuthor

╒════════╤═════════════════╕
│"p.name"│"followingAuthor"│
╞════════╪═════════════════╡
│"Post 3"│true             │
├────────┼─────────────────┤
│"Post 2"│true             │
├────────┼─────────────────┤
│"Post 1"│false            │
└────────┴─────────────────┘
```
````

Comment: Wow! Great call with putting (thing) there and not (Thing), and then making that relationship directionless! Makes it so it can be any node at all, which is really smart. Thank you a ton!

Comment: If somebody follows a person who was the author, and also follows a Thing that was tagged in a post, currently they both return. So I put RETURN DISTINCT p, is that the best option here for avoiding duplicates (seems so!)? Thank you again!!

Comment: It’s a good option. You can also take advantage of Cypher’s implicit GroupBy when using aggregating functions, for example RETURN p, count(*) AS score in case you would like to rank the results